# Yii2 dropDownList

Tags: php, sql

Preciso de um exemplo, de dropDownList, onde eu possa fazer um dropDown entre dois sqls, neste caso A e B.

Abaixo apresento um pseudocódigo.

**Introdução ao problema:**

Tabela sql A

```
id_A
id_usuario
nome_A
descricao_A
```

Tabela sql B

```
id_B
id_A
nome_B
descricao_B
```

Preciso fazer um dropDownList com o sql B, onde deverá ser apresentado todos os campos do sql A que tenham o `id_usuario = 10`, porém no sql B não possuo o campo id_usuario, deverá algo do tipo inner join, porém usando o dropDownList do yii2.

A sintaxe abaixo, que estou usando não resolve, pois somente apresenta os campos 
que satisfaz o id_A (sql A e B).

```
dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(B::find()->where(['id_A' => $A->id_A])->all(),'id_B','nome_B') ,
```

P.S. Não quero colocar o id_usuario no sql B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, no exemplo acima basta realizar a seguinte modificação:

```
$id_usuario = Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();

dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(B::find()->([A])->where(['id_usuario' => $id_usuario])->all(),'id_B','nome_B')
```